# How to access a buttons that has never been formaly declared?

Tags: java, button, for-loop, actionlistener, timeline

Hi I have this loop that created buttons for each of the number between an interval and I was wondering how do I access the action listener of these buttons?

```
   ////FOR EACH DATE
   for (int i=(timeLine.getInterval())[0]; i<(timeLine.getInterval())[1] +1; i++)
   {
    listPanel.add(new JButton(""+i));

   }
```

Normaly I would do this:

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()...
```

but I dont have a name set to any of my buttons because the ammount is indefinite. Thank you:)

Comment: It's a very wide question and can have many correct answers depending on what you actually want. `listPanel.get(index).addActionListener()..` you can get the reference and add a listener like that in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a generic ActionListener that can be used for all the buttons. The ActionListener will get the source of the event and then use information from the button to do process.

For example here is how you can create a simple "calculator panel" by using buttons that have the same functionality:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class CalculatorPanel extends JPanel
{
    private JTextField display;

    public CalculatorPanel()
    {
        Action numberAction = new AbstractAction()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
//              display.setCaretPosition( display.getDocument().getLength() );
                display.replaceSelection(e.getActionCommand());
            }
        };

        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

        display = new JTextField();
        display.setEditable( false );
        display.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
        add(display, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setLayout( new GridLayout(0, 5) );
        add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            String text = String.valueOf(i);
            JButton button = new JButton( text );
            button.addActionListener( numberAction );
            button.setBorder( new LineBorder(Color.BLACK) );
            button.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(30, 30) );
            buttonPanel.add( button );

            InputMap inputMap = button.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(text), text);
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("NUMPAD" + text), text);
            button.getActionMap().put(text, numberAction);
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Calculator Panel");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.add( new CalculatorPanel() );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the new button to temp variable, and you need to be able to use the "amount" in the action:

```
 for (int i=(timeLine.getInterval())[0]; i<(timeLine.getInterval())[1] +1; i++)
   {
    JButon b = new JButton(""+i);
    final int amount = i;
    b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           // do something with amount
           aplyAmount(amount);
       } 

    });
    listPanel.add(b);

   }
```